# Associating two models together in Rails 4+

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, associations, models

I have a User model which is working under Devise with no problems (using devise sanitizer to update fields, so no UsersController) 
I am working on creating a Quiz model, which belongs_to the User model, and the User model has_one Quiz. In my routes, I have: resources :users, :quizzes (is this supposed to be quizzes or quizs? I know that Rails pluralizes but couldn't seem to find which it'd be in this case).

In my views, I'm trying to open up a modal (which works) and inside have it populated with fields that a User can enter in questions they want (q1 through q5 being the database fields).
Inside the modal content area, I have the code:

```
<%= form_for @quiz, url: {action: "new"} do |f| %>
<%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

and I get the error "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty"

Inside my quizzes controller, I have defined new as

```
def new
@quiz = Quiz.new
end
```

I would greatly appreciate some assistance here! Thank you.

Comment: did you try run Quiz.new on rails console and what is its output?

Comment: @power <Quiz id: nil, q1: nil, q2: nil, q3: nil, q4: nil, q5: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Comment: also the modal which you are using is placed inside the app/view/quizzes/new.html.erb or you are render your modal inside new.html.erb?

Comment: @power Under views, I have a folder called "Welcome" and inside is landing.html.erb where I have all my code (the stuff aside from HTML being some listings of the current user's data)

Comment: does `landing.html.erb `has controller? can you post it if it does.. the problem is @quiz is nil and you have not initialize it

Comment: @Marv-C there's a WelcomeController and it has 'index' and 'landing' as methods, but both are empty.

Comment: then in index define it there `@quiz = Quiz.new`

Comment: @Marv-C It worked!!!!! Thanks so much!

Comment: you're welcome. ill post the answer if you dont mind.

Comment: @Marv-C Somewhat unrelated to this question, but do you know:

If I entered in something in for q1 for example, how could I display it?

I'm displaying user info as current_user.username (for example) right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117376/discussion-between-helpisgood-and-marv-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `WelcomeController` action: `index` add this line to initialized @quiz

```
def index 
  @quiz = Quiz.new
end
```

hope you made a good progress in your project.

Answer (score 1):

shoudn't it be like following

```
<%= form_for @quiz do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```